# Regex for some specific conditions

Tags: c#, regex

Characters with max length 9
Alphanumeric with a minimum 4 numeric characters (numbers must be at position 3 and 4 ) & maximum of 2 letter E.G. 345678876, aa1234,1234aa, a1243a

I have tried 
/[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,1}^.{2,3}[0-9]{1,6}$/

Comment: Please share your code - you have tried so far

Comment: And a large coke with that please. Please consider reading the rules of SO, try taking the Tour. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Try https://regexr.com it's be fun. However, `regex` in general cannot [cleanly] express conditions like `contains at least/most N characters of given class anywhere in a string`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language for the deep details!

Comment: A Regex like this should do the trick: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,9}^.{2,3}[0-9]{4,}[a-zA-Z]{0,2}$`

Answer (score 0):

For you conditions:

- Characters with max length 9 Alphanumeric
- minimum 4 numeric characters (numbers must be at position 3 and 4)
- maximum of 2 letter

You could use positive and negative lookaheads:

```
^(?!.{10}$)(?!(?:.*[a-z]){3})(?=(?:.*[0-9]){4})[a-z0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}[a-z0-9]*$
```

**Pattern parts**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.{10}$)` Assert string length of 10
- `(?!(?:.*[a-z]){3})` Assert no more than 3 chars a-z
- `(?=(?:.*[0-9]){4})` Assert at least 4 digits
- `[a-z0-9]{2}` Match 2 times any of the listed
- `[0-9]{2}` Match 2 times 0-9
- `[a-z0-9]*` Match 0+ times any of the listed
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RUKDho/1)